# Get the contents of multiple cells to print in a msgbox

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

I have a spreadsheet that I am running a macro against and at the end of the macro, I want it to take content of all of the populated cells in row 1 (the number of populated cells will differ each time it runs) and print the contents of those cell out together into a msgbox.

Here's my sheet
[image: Example data]

I would like a box to concatenate the data from columns A - D and display it like this:
4 Applications and Technologies, including the following Gold and Platinum Tier: ABC, DEF, GHI, JKL

*(please keep in mind that each time I run this the number of columns with text will change.  Sometimes there will be only A and B, others there may be 300 or more, which is why I'm trying to use a range)*.

I can't figure out how to get the message box to select all of the cells in row 1 with content and then display that content in the message box.  Instead I get this:
[image: MsgBox Output]

Here is my macro:

```
Sub TLA_2()

' Count the rows and display the message
Dim No_Of_Rows As Integer
No_Of_Rows = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

'MsgBox No_Of_Rows, vbOKOnly, "Total Number of Applications"
        
Range("A1").Select
MsgBox No_Of_Rows & " Applications and Technologies, including the following Gold and Platinum Tiers: " & Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

End Sub
```

I know my problem is that I have that .Select at the end of my range and that I'm getting "true" because it selected the data.  What I cannot figure out is how to get it to produce the VALUE of that selection instead of just confirming the selection happened.

I have also tried using a variable concept but that didn't work:

```
Range("A1").Select
Dim paragraph As Object
paragraph = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Text
MsgBox No_Of_Rows & " Applications and Technologies, including the following Gold and Platinum Tiers: " & paragraph
```

I know this is going to be a really dumb novice thing, but I am stuck!

Comment: You can loop through the cells and concatenate their values using `&`, or use `WorksheetFunction.Concat` if your version of Excel supports it.

Comment: Thank you!  Would you be able to assist me in figuring out how to write that?  I am VERY new to VBA so I am figuring out how to do stuff by dissecting examples :)

Comment: Are you doing it for each row, one at a time, or just one row?

Comment: There will be only 1 row of data, but there will be a variable number of columns in that row that contain data.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your setup you'll need data in the rows below 1 to be able to use xlEndDown! You'll also need a Dynamic Range name for Row 1 as follows:

```
MsgBox =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$1),1000)

Note: this allows for 1000 columns max of premium tiers, adjust as necessary.
```

This code will work if you select the cell that contains the first item in your row data, in the example A2.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DisplayResults()

  Dim No_Of_Rows As Integer
  Dim BaseMsg    As String
  Dim Tiers      As String
  Dim Cell       As Range
  
  BaseMsg = " Applications and Technologies, including the following Gold and Platinum Tier:"
  
  No_Of_Rows = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

  For Each Cell In Range("MsgData")
    Tiers = Tiers & Cell.Value
  Next Cell
  
  MsgBox No_Of_Rows & BaseMsg & vbCrLf & Tiers, vbOKOnly, "Results:"
  
End Sub 'DisplayResults
```

[image]

HTH